# Error on customers computer

Tags: java, client

I have a java client server program that works fine on a half a dozen computere but is causing a NegativeArraySizeException on site.

This is the code

```
location = message.indexOf("last");
location += 5;
end = message.indexOf('&', location);
int size = end - location;  THIS IS THE ERROR LINE
char[] lastC = new char[size];
message.getChars(location, location+size, lastC, 0);
String firstS = new String(firstC);
String lastS = new String(lastC);
```

message is an xml message I am reading.
location is an integer that points the the location of a character in the message, the first name in this case.
size is the length of the persons name.

As far as I can tell size is being set as a negative number and I don't know why.

Does anyone know how to fix this or a better was of finding the length of the name ?

This is part of the server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trouble is that end is less than location. The issue is what message are you expecting and which one you are receiving; the rest of the logic works for certain messages. Check from where you get your message String.

Answer (score 2):

Does the message contain `last` at all? If not, `location` would be negative, and you should stop processing right there. This error might go unnoticed because you add 5 to `location` after that, which makes it equal to at least 4 even if `last` is not in the string (thanks [SJuan76](https://stackoverflow.com/users/598289/sjuan76)).

Even if the message contains `last`, is it guaranteed that it is followed by at least one extra character? If not, adding 5 to `location` would point outside the string for sure.

Moreover, `end` may also be negative if there is no `&` in the string after `location`. You should handle that somehow (i.e. by setting `end` to the length of the message in that case).

Also, if `message` is a string, you can simply extract a substring of it using the `substring` method, no need for the `getChars` magic.

A better solution would probably be something like this (I'm assuming that `message` is something like an URL and you are looking for the part between `last>` and the next `&`, based on your comment for one of the other answers):

```
location = message.indexOf("last>");
if (location >= 0) {
    String lastS;

    location += 5;
    end = message.indexOf('&', location);
    if (end == -1) {
        // Handle the case when there is no "&" after "last>" in the message
    } else {
        lastS = message.substring(location, end);
    }
} else {
    // Handle the case when there is no "last>" in the message
}
```

Comment: loction is at least 4, because he adds 5. Anyway the issue is what message is he expecting, what is he receiving, and why the discrepance. The rest of the code just works if the message is valid (but we do not know what makes it valid)

Comment: i am trying to get a persons name from an xml message, as everyone's name is a different size I could not use a default so I came up with this. lastS = message.substring(location); would this not just copy all of the message that is left ?

Comment: @Skeith: yes, it would, but it happens only when ``end`` is -1, which means that there is no ``&`` in the string after the ``last=`` part. I have assumed that in this case, you need the entire substring that is left. If that is not the case, you have to handle the case of ``end`` being -1 differently.

Comment: the message does contain an &, see the comment below

Comment: @Skeith: updated my code snippet to look for ``last>`` and not try to take the whole remaining string if there is no ``&`` after ``last>``. This should work I think, but you should probably go back to whoever gave you that message and whack him in the head because that is not well-formed XML at all.

Answer (score 2):

> As far as I can tell size is being set as a negative number and I don't know why.

If the first call to `indexOf` cannot locate `"last"` in the message, then location will be set to `-1` and then incremented by `5` to give `4`.

If the second call to `indexOf` cannot find a `'&'` then `end` will be set to `-1`, and `size` will be negative.

Obviously, the input XML is not in the form you expect.

All in all, that code is pretty dodgy.  As a minimum you should check the results of both calls to `indexOf` and take appropriate error reporting / recovery steps if they are `-1`.

But the real fix is to not attempt to "parse" XML using crufty string bashing.  Use an XML parser, preferably with validation against the relevant schema or DTD.  If the XML parser rejects the input, report the error back at who / whatever gave you the broken XML.

Comment: I have a copy of the xml message that is being sent and it has the &, it is the same test message that worked on all the test machines. second telling me my code is shit is not helpful and thirdly this is supposed to be an xml parser.

Comment: @SKeith - show us the XML.  Actually, pointing out that your code is "shit"  (and that is YOUR description, not mine!) **is helpful** if it persuades you to write it properly.  And even if it is only helpful to your poor clients.

Comment: Actually, I even suspect that this might not be XML at all. XML strings do not have ampersands floating around unless you meant to write ``&lt;``, ``&gt;``, ``&amp;`` or something similar.

Comment: @ Stephen C This is the most revelat bit of the message count="1">&lt;shareresults resno="1000PQ">&lt;guestresults guestnum="10000C">&lt;guestnum>10000C&lt;/guestnum>&lt;title>Mr.&lt;/title>&lt;last>Downing&lt;/last>&lt;first>Rick&lt;/first>&lt;address1>

Comment: @SKeith - that is definitely not well-formed XML.  It looks like the `<` characters for the XML start and end tags have been replaced with character entities.

Comment: @Stephen c its not my xml, it's a protocol I am interfacing with and I have to parse it to get the useful information.

Comment: @SKeith - that is so "not XML" that I strongly suspect that something is mangling it before you see it.  Suggest you look into that.  Maybe once the cause for the mangling has been resolved you can use a real XML parser.  I think it would also help if you reviewed the XML specifications (at least XML 1.1) to understand some of the complexities of parsing XML by hand.

Comment: The xml is a test script given to me by the company that I an interfacing out product with. I have a cc++ version that works fine and a java version that works on every machine but the one the client is using and i thought as i am not very good at java I may have used the wrong function for string hacking.

Comment: @Skeith - as I said, it is patently not XML.  Perhaps it was originally XML and you or they mangled it in transit.  Perhaps you've just spent may hours coding against a mangled test file.  You would be wise to check with them **before** you waste more of your / their time.

Comment: @SKeith - if you do want to persist with string bashing this mangled XML, we've provided you with a diagnosis of the immediate cause.  You next step should be to modify your "parser" to be more robust, and provide you with more information about the context when it fails.  If that approach doesn't help, you will need to debug this on the client's machine.